# how use jquery to get selected value using simple form of ruby on rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, simple-form

i have a problem to get the value of a selected value from a dropdownlist

my code jquery is : `$( "#statistic_commune option:selected" ).text();`

this code work when i use just html like : `select.form-control name="statistic[state]" id="statistic_commune "`

but it doesn't work when i use : rails tag like `= towns_select_tag(:statistic, :commune, {include_blank: true}, {class: 'form-control'},{id: 'statistic_commune'})`

help please

Comment: Try to inspect element and see what actual id is there in select tag

Comment: Show us what the rendered html looks like and where you are calling this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do like this

```
= towns_select_tag(:statistic, :commune, {include_blank: true}, {class: 'form-control'}, :id => "statistic_commune")
```

You should get value by using:

```
$('#statistic_commune').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to target the select tag :

```
$( "#statistic_commune" ).val();
```